# Why does Hadoop MapReduce perform disk read/write in each iteration for iterative algorithms ？

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know that for iterative algorithms，Hadoop mapreduce doesn't perform well since it does a complete disk read/write for each iteration. But why？Is that for the robustness of the system？

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit broad but still, I would try to answer it.

Hadoop do the disk read/write operation for any algorithm is due to the fact that Hadoop does disk oriented processing and it was built on this principle. It is also one of the reasons why spark was developed, to move the computation from disk to memory so that it can decrease latency overhead of disk oriented computation.

Now this read/write operation from/to disk for each MapReduce iteration contribute to the system robustness and also reliability.Consider a simplest example that a worker node has 2 containers which mean two separate JVM will be running on the same machine and they will access the same data source available on that node. Thus if the Hadoop will not read/write on disk for each change then there is a possibility that second container when accessed the data it was not updated with changes and it can lead to corrupt and noisy output. 
That is one of the reasons Hadoop do read and write to disk for each iterative map reduce algorithm.

Hope this answer your query.

Comment: Well, you mention Hadoop does disk oriented processing, why the developers design in this way? Just for better robustness?

Comment: Robustness is one of the many thing like cost effective, flexible etc. which this achieve. Moreover hadoop was designed to do processing on large dataset and for achieving that Doug cutting like the idea of big table where distributed computing was used with disk oriented computation to process very large dataset and they decided to adopt big table because with this they were able to process very large amount of data which was not possible earlier and In the beginning this was the target.once Developers were able to do that then they decided to make it fast with memory computation.

Comment: So you mean other than robustness, Hadoop MapReduce does that way because at that time some applications conduct distributed computing with the help of disk oriented computation? My point is why memory-based processing framework such as Spark is created after the disk-oriented Hadoop MapReduce? Is that because Hadoop mainly solves issues for distributed storage at that time, while Spark can't show its advantage without a proper distributed file system?

Comment: Memory based frameworks like spark are created because they are faster, more sophisticated like it do lazy evaluation using resilient graphs, real time stream data processing and it also support machine learning lib which was not possible with map reduce in hadoop. And yes spark can not show its advantage without a effective distributed file system or database. Today also most people use spark with HDfS for data storage because of its reliability.

Comment: Thanks, I get it.